# What is wrong with my function?

Tags: php

Here is my code for the function

```
 function multiple_delete($checkbox, $table = 0, $url = 0, $picture1 = 0, $picture2 = 0, $picture3 = 0){
          echo $count = count($checkbox);
     for( $j=0;$j<$count;$j++)
          {
          $delete_id = $checkbox[$j];
          $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = '$delete_id'";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

     if( $picture1 !== 0 && $picture2 !== 0 && $picture3 !== 0) 
         {
         $pic_1 = $picture1;
         $pic_2 = $picture2;
         $pic_3 = $picture3;
         unlink($pic_1);
         unlink($pic_2);
         unlink($pic_3);
         continue;
         }
     if( $picture1 !== 0 && $picture2 !== 0 && $picture3 == 0 ) 
         { 
         $pic_1 = $picture1;
         $pic_2 = $picture2;
         unlink($pic_1);
         unlink($pic_2);
         continue;
         }
         }

     for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)   {
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id='$del_id'";
        $result_delete_data = mysql_query($sql);
        }
        alert('Deleted Successfully');
        redirect_url($url);
        return true;
        }
```

My Problem is when i call the function using the following code.

```
@multiple_delete($_POST['checkbox'], 'news', 'news.php', '$row[\'pic_title\']', '$row[\'pic_brief\']', '$row[\'pic_detail\']');
```

the three array variables $row['pic_title'], $row['pic_brief'], $row['pic_detail'] , does not parse as the value in the function in first for loop, instead it just print the string and hence is not able to fetch the value stored in the database. for example

in the first  if condition i have defined 3 variables,

```
 $pic_1 = $picture1;
 $pic_2 = $picture2;
 $pic_3 = $picture3;
```

$picture1, $picture2, and $picture3 holds the value that i declared in the function , now when i do something like this `echo $pic_1 = $picture1;` it prints `$row['pic_title']`  the exact value which i declared in the function instead of parsing the value which is actually `upload/news/title/pic_title1.jpg` i tried testing it like this, instead of declaring the value in the defined function i actually just changed the value of the three variables to

```
 $pic_1 = $row['pic_title'];
 $pic_2 = $row['pic_brief'];
 $pic_3 = $row['pic_detail'];
```

this works very fine without any problem. why is that variable $picture1 which holds the value $row['pic_title']; refuses to parse it and force it to just print the string while if i change it manually it works? where i am going wrong?

apart from the last three parameters i dont have any problem parsing the first three parameters it works perfectly fine i have tested it in many ways. the only problem i am facing is of the last three parameters

Edit : i tried double quotes, single quotes, and single quotes with double quote with the combination of concatenation operator. without quotes. nothing works.

P.S : thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using error suppression (`@`) there?

Comment: simply because when using the function it will print the error as $row['pic_title']  array is undefined.

Comment: @Ibrahim: then you should fix that, not suppress the error and pretend it isn't there.

Comment: @BoltClock i am able to execute the query if i change the value inside the function the only problem i am facing is while declaring. the last three parameters refuses to pass the value instead it just print the string wherever it is defined.

Comment: @BoltClock that serves no meaning i just want it as a string and passed in function as a value. the only way i found it out to fix it by again qurying the database while function call, that is the weird logic i guess, i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Could you show us how you assign values to the array before you call the function? That is where the error is probably.

Comment: @captaintokyo i dont assign the value to the array $row, i just define it as a string in function call, check this code, @multiple_delete($_POST['checkbox'], 'news', 'news.php', '$row[\'pic_title\']', '$row[\'pic_brief\']', '$row[\'pic_detail\']'); this is how i directly assigned the array as a string in the function call, i am not able to understand on why does it not parse the value from the string in the loop?

Comment: @Ibrahim There's something fundamentally wrong with your understanding of how argument passing works. You don't simply pass a string and expect it to be "parsed".

Comment: @NullUserException it parses the first three parameters without any problem, the only problem i am facing is of the last three. and that is array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function multiple_delete($checkbox, $table, $url, $picture1, $picture2, $picture3){
    echo $count = count($checkbox);

    for($j=0; $j<$count; $j++)
    {
        $delete_id = $checkbox[$j];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = '$delete_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $pic1 = $row[$picture1];
        $pic2 = $row[$picture2];
        $pic3 = $row[$picture3];

        if(!empty($pic1) && !empty($pic2) && !empty($pic3))
        {
            unlink($pic1);
            unlink($pic2);
            unlink($pic3);
        }
        else if(!empty($pic1) && !empty($pic2))
        {
            unlink($pic1);
            unlink($pic2);
        }

        $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id='$delete_id'";
        $result_delete_data = mysql_query($sql);
    }

    // this is javascript, not php
    // alert('Deleted Successfully');
    redirect_url($url);
    return true;
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
multiple_delete($_POST['checkbox_name'], 'table_name', 'redirect_url', 'column_name_pic_1', 'column_name_pic_2', 'column_name_pic_3');
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the apostrophes around your variable names in the function call, ie try

```
, $row[\'pic_title\'],
```

instead of

```
, '$row[\'pic_title\']',
```

Comment: the code you have asked me to check is wrong syntax. instead it should be $row['pic_title'] without the backslash. now this too doesnt work if i try using this it does not print anything at all. i tried double quotes, single quotes, and single quotes with double quote with the combination of concatenation operator, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this problem. in case it can benefit anyone here is the link to the solution.

[How do i parse the the value from a string in the function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590278/how-do-i-parse-the-the-value-from-a-string-in-the-function-call)